# Excel Repeating Axis Label for Graphic

Tags: excel

I have a data structure like this,

```
Cpt. Date   Route   Juni    Juli    Agustus


  Rout  Cpt. Date       Juni    Juli    Agustus
  AMQCGK    Lastweek    2,67    1,39    6,79
  AMQCGK    Today       2,88    1,61    7,16
  AMQSUB    Lastweek    0,00    3,53    0,31
  AMQSUB    Today       0,35    6,38    0,52
```

I have to generated a graphic like below :

[image]

There's a repeated axis label on it. How can I remove it?
I want Route AMQCGK to only show once.

Comment: A quick fix is to delete the second occurrence of AMQCGK in the spreadsheet data, or to merge these two cells. Neither is ideal though: it is not generally a good practice to alter the table to achieve an effect in a chart, and removing this value will interfere with sorting, etc., of the table. And merged cells are horrible things.

Comment: Otherwise, if it is only for this one chart, and it won't change often, you could just place a shape on top of the chart.

Comment: if i delete that data in spreadsheet, theres still line on it that separated lastweek and today data.

then, this just only dummy data. the actual data contain many routes, so the third solution is imposible.

Thank you for your responses

Comment: If you just want to get rid of lines then double-click the axis and change its Marker properties.